# How to get ctx value in JMeter using step-by-step debugger plugin?

Tags: debugging, jmeter, blazemeter

I just installed the step-by-step debugger plugin and it seems very helpful.
I read it from here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-debugger-jmeter-it%E2%80%99s-not-dream-anymore
I am using a sampler SMTP which is inside an IF Controller.
Please how can I see what is the full content of my ctx variable that I am currenty using this way?

```
${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName())}
```

Clicking on stepover and looking at my vars I can only see those variables:

[image]

and those jmeter properties:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your groovy to this `${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName(),MyVar)}` // **MyVar** is the variable name that will hold the value.

Then add a [debug sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [view result tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and check your debug sampler to see what is the value of your variable **MyVar**

Comment: thanks @ararar, where should I add this x   ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName(),MyVar)}? Currently I am just using ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName())} in the body of the email I am sending with my SMTP Sampler

Comment: Im sorry it should be ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName(),MyVar)} i will edit the answer with this

Comment: And you should adjust it wherever you are using it